# Accesing class variable from another script using python

Tags: python, class, import

I am facing weird error when I try to access `self.cursor_dat' from class in different script. It says:`ImportError: cannot import name query_selection_class`. The error also occur without trying to access the variable. There is just something wrong with the import command.

here is the **file1.py** where I create the variable:

```
class connection_settings_class(QtGui.QMainWindow,Ui_main_connection_settings_window):
    def __init__(self):
        self.create_connection_window()
        self.host = 'localhost'
        self.port = '3307'
        self.user = 'root'
        self.password = ''
        self.database = 'rtr'

    def connection(self):
        """ connect to the database and create cursor that will be used to exetute MySQL queries """
        try:
             self.cnxn = pyodbc.connect(driver = '{MySQL ODBC 5.3 ANSI Driver}',  # ANSI or Unicode
                                        host = self.host,
                                        port = self.port,
                                        user = self.user,
                                        password = self.password,
                                        database = self.database)
        except:
            print('Connection FAIL')

        **self.cursor_dat** = self.cnxn.cursor()
        **self.cursor_dat**.execute("""SELECT * FROM test_db.attempt;""")
        row = **self.cursor_dat**.fetchone()
        if row:
            print("Succesfully connected to the database.")
            print row
            self.status_label.setText("Connected")
        else:
            print("Connection FAIL")
            self.status_label.setText("Disconnected")

    def create_connection_window(self):
        ...rest of the code
```

...and here is **file2**

```
import file1  -> I also tried from file1 import connection_settings_class


class plausible_implausible_class(QtGui.QMainWindow,Ui_plausible_implausible_win):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.show()
    sc = MyStaticMplCanvas(self.centralwidget, width=500, height=400, dpi=100)
    self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(sc)
    **a = file1.connection_settings_class.cursor_dat**
```

Comment: ignore the **star** signs, I just tried to highlight the variable...

Comment: Which python version are you running? Are you running this from the directory that holds `file1.py`? If you are not on the command line, use `os.getcwd()` to verify. Does `import file1` fail? Right after`import file1` print `file1.__file__` to see if you are importing the module you think you are. If you have a `file1.pyc` file in your directory, delete it.

Comment: I am running python 2.7.11 and everything is in the same folder. How can I run file1.__file__ right after the import command, when it fails immediately after importing?

Comment: When you `import file1` you get `ImportError: No module named file1`? That means that python couldn't find the module in the paths listed in `sys.path`. You could run through them yourself before import with `for path in sys.path: print '%s --> %s' % (repr(path), os.path.exists(os.path.join(path, 'file1.py')))` to check the paths. The most interesting one is the current directory. Simply trying `open('file1.py')` would be interesting. Also, `print os.getcwd()`

Comment: Thank you very much for help. I finally solved it. The problem wasnt in paths but in crossing of imports. If you are interested see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, there is not problem with the path because all the scripts that @tdelaney mentioned were positive. The result of for cycle is **'/Users/BauchMAC/PycharmProjects/py_GUI/Database_GUI' --> True**. And the working directory which I got using os.getcwd() is same.

I also tried to create two new scripts and everything worked. So the problem is that I don't understand to "importing rules" in python because this is the source of the problem.

So there is obviously problem with **crossing of imports**. And the way to solve it is by passing the value as the parameter.

Below you can see how I wanted to do it and the reason for the error:

file1:

```
from try4 import ClassB

class ClassA():
    def __init__(self):
        self.cursor_dat = 1
        self.query_selection_win = ClassB()

object1 = ClassA()
```

file 2:

```
from try3 import ClassA <-- source of the probles

class ClassB():
    def __init__(self, cursor_dat):
        print(ClassA.cursor_dat)
```

And here is how it should be (at least it works, I am not sure if it is the best way how to do it, I am still newbie)

file 1:

```
from try4 import ClassB

class ClassA():
    def __init__(self):
        self.cursor_dat = 1
        self.query_selection_win = ClassB(self.cursor_dat)

object1 = ClassA()
```

file 2:

```
class ClassB():
    def __init__(self, cursor_dat):
        print(cursor_dat)
```

I hope it will be helpful to some newbie like me :)

Answer (score 0):

I might be making a really dumb mistake looking at your sample, but what I see is this:

```
 self.cursor_dat= self.cnxn.cursor()
```

is defined in the `connection_settings_class.connection()` method. You never call `connection()`, so that property never gets created.

Also I noticed that you're calling the class statically, rather than creating an instance of the class but you've created no static properties, they're all created on `__init__`. You may want to create an instance of your class, which then defines the `cursor_dat` to be `None` initially.

If you want connection sharing you can set up a pool of connections and still create individual instances.

Comment: No, this isn't a problem. That line is in the `connection` method directly below the line where it sets the variable. And it doesn't explain the import error.